# Why is using NOT with implication a bad idea in SVA?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

In SystemVerilog Assertions (SVA), why is using:

```
not (a |-> b)
```

a bad idea?  Is it due to the vacuous success aspect of the implication (i.e., when `a` is not true)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Due to the vacuous passes, if `a` is false your property will not hold.

Answer (score 0):

This statement would work only if a is true. If a is false then the assertion will return true irrespective of what the value of b is.